# Custom software with OpenVpn, weird error in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, domain, openvpn

We have some software that programmatically installs a network adapter for [OpenVpn](http://openvpn.net/).  It is a loopback adapter that sets up a vpn on Windows.

The installation keeps failing and rolling back.  So we tried to do some stuff manually.

If you manually install the driver, then try to disable it from Windows explorer (which the setup does), we get this error message:

```
It is not possible to disable the connection at this time.  This connection may be using one or more protocols that do not support Plug-and-Play, or it may have been initiated by another user or system account.
```

We have gotten this to occur on 2 different PCs (One Vista, One Windows XP).  Only thing in common, is they are both setup on a domain.  In both cases we are running from an admin user, with no UAC enabled or anything.

Any insights into this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd answer to help others that might come across this issue.

We reinstalled windows on the machines in question, this fixed our issue.

It turns out there were some WMI database issues that we diagnosed with [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7684) tool.